# How to access API endpoint on EC2 bypassing ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to access an API endpoint deployed on AWS EC2 instance bypassing the ELB ? I can see the API is registered with a Load Balancer. Can I use the Public DNS of the EC2 instance to access it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can (as long as the security group allows so). You can also use the public IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding an inbound rule to the security group allowing all IP addresses but still unable to access the API endpoint. Maybe I did it wrong. Appreciate if some steps can be shared.

Comment: checked again and found that I have changed inbound rule for a different endpoint and corrected it. Now it's working fine. Thanks a lot